# How to copy a zip file from Windows to CentOS

Tags: centos, scp

On a Windows machine, I have a zip file in my `E:\` directory. I want to import this onto my CentOS system inside the directory `user/user01`.

I know the command must involve `scp`, but I am unable to find the exact format for the command. I get an error like `cp: cannot stat 'IOT.zip': No such file or directory"`.

How do I get rid of this error?

Comment: Is Windows on a different machine? You are not dual booting and the E directory is on the same machine and a different partition? If Windows is on the same machine as Linux then you can't use scp. If Windows is on its own separate machine then it needs to be running an ssh server, is that the case? If so, is port 22 open on the Windows firewall?

Comment: As you have ssh access, try WinSCP > https://winscp.net/eng/download.php or are you asking for the command from Windows?

Answer (score 1):

Easier still I would suggest using a program such as WinSCP which is a windows gui you can use to pop the files on via SFTP. Just download it (google winscp) and connect using SSH details

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to check a network drive hosted by a windows machine I don't think you would be using ssh; unless it was set up that way. Probably would be a samba server.

Here is the man page for smbclient, there is probably better/more information out there for smb. duckduck it.

https://linux.die.net/man/1/smbclient